# Searching for a key inside dictionary tuple keys in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Whilst trying to run the following code:

```
temp3 = {
    ('EUR-EURIBOR-1Y-SWAPTION-PHYSICAL-ANNUAL-BOND-QUANTO-USD','EUR-EURIBOR-1Y-SWAPTION-PHYSICAL-ANNUAL-BOND-QUANTO-GBP'):'EURIBOR_EUR_1Y'
}

print (temp3.get('EUR-EURIBOR-1Y-SWAPTION-PHYSICAL-ANNUAL-BOND-QUANTO-USD'))
```

**Output:**

```
None
```

**Expected:**

```
EURIBOR_EUR_1Y
```

Comment: EURIBOR_EUR_1Y is not a key but value for the first tuple which acts as your dictionary, read this like:
('EUR-EURIBOR-1Y-SWAPTION-PHYSICAL-ANNUAL-BOND-QUANTO-USD','EUR-EURIBOR-1Y-SWAPTION-PHYSICAL-ANNUAL-BOND-QUANTO-GBP'): 'EURIBOR_EUR_1Y'

Comment: What is that? a key of tuple with a str value?

Comment: I assumed that within the brackets it takes is as OR rather than AND.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're expecting the `get` function to unpack the `key` values and search inside the tuples; it doesn't work that way.

The correct way is to use the `key` that you used to create the `dict`.

**Example:**

```
temp3 = {
    ('EUR-EURIBOR-1Y-SWAPTION-PHYSICAL-ANNUAL-BOND-QUANTO-USD',
     'EUR-EURIBOR-1Y-SWAPTION-PHYSICAL-ANNUAL-BOND-QUANTO-GBP'):'EURIBOR_EUR_1Y'
}

print(temp3.get(('EUR-EURIBOR-1Y-SWAPTION-PHYSICAL-ANNUAL-BOND-QUANTO-USD',
     'EUR-EURIBOR-1Y-SWAPTION-PHYSICAL-ANNUAL-BOND-QUANTO-GBP')))
```

Which will output the key; to get *all* values that have the key that matches you can use the following:

```
def key_search(needle, haystack):
    matches = []

    for key, value in haystack.items():
        if type(key) in [list, tuple, dict] and needle in key:
            matches.append(value)
        elif needle == key:
            matches.append(value)

    return matches

data = {
    (1, 2, 3): 'heyyy',
    (2, 1): 'heyyy there'
}

print(key_search(1, data))
```

**Output**

```
['heyyy there', 'heyyy']
```

Where `needle` is the key you're looking for, and the haystack is your data.

Comment: I assumed that within the brackets it takes is as OR rather than AND. What I wanted to do was if either of the keys in the bracket are provided, it returns one value as stated.

Comment: I updated the question with a solution. You can either use that or go for `yield` which is a generator.

Comment: If you need just one match, you can remove `matches = []` and replace `matches.append(value)` with `return value`

Comment: I was also thinking along the same lines but since I have to hand this code over to someone else. I think easiest would be to separate each pair out. Thank you very much, greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the correct key is `('EUR-EURIBOR-1Y-SWAPTION-PHYSICAL-ANNUAL-BOND-QUANTO-USD','EUR-EURIBOR-1Y-SWAPTION-PHYSICAL-ANNUAL-BOND-QUANTO-GBP')`

So if you'll try:

```
print(temp3.get(('EUR-EURIBOR-1Y-SWAPTION-PHYSICAL-ANNUAL-BOND-QUANTO-USD','EUR-EURIBOR-1Y-SWAPTION-PHYSICAL-ANNUAL-BOND-QUANTO-GBP')))
```

You'll get:

```
EURIBOR_EUR_1Y
```

Comment: I assumed that within the brackets it takes is as OR rather than AND. What I wanted to do was if either of the keys in the bracket are provided, it returns one value as stated.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the complete key for the dictionary.

Try with complete key

```
(temp3.get('EUR-EURIBOR-1Y-SWAPTION-PHYSICAL-ANNUAL-BOND-QUANTO-USD','EUR-EURIBOR-1Y-SWAPTION-PHYSICAL-ANNUAL-BOND-QUANTO-GBP'))
'EUR-EURIBOR-1Y-SWAPTION-PHYSICAL-ANNUAL-BOND-QUANTO-GBP'
```

Comment: I assumed that within the brackets it takes is as OR rather than AND. What I wanted to do was if either of the keys in the bracket are provided, it returns one value as stated.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking

```
print(temp3.get([i for i in temp3 if 'EUR-EURIBOR-1Y-SWAPTION-PHYSICAL-ANNUAL-BOND-QUANTO-USD' in i][0]))
```

*Output:*

```
EURIBOR_EUR_1Y
```